# Accessing to columns and rows on a dataframe and summing specific rows based on columns specified in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rowsum

My data are structured in a list (named L) of length 6, so it contains 6 dataframes. I'm correctly accessing the df i want (named D) with: `L[[dfname]]`.
My target is to get the sum of a row identified by a vector from another dataframe (named Dselect) selecting one specific row number of D with `Dselect$row` and specific columns (one or more) associated to that row  contained in a list (named Lselect) i can access with the id contained in `Dselect$idforcolumn`. Here's an example of my objects:

```
D
   01 02 03
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  3
3  0  0  0
4  3  2  1

Dselect
   row idforcolumn
1  1   103285
2  2   103346

Lselect
$103285
[1] "01" "02" 

$103346
[1] "03"
```

What could be the solution besides structuring my data in a different way?
I thought about something like summing `D[ Dselect$row, Lselect[[Dselect$idforcolumn]] ]`. The objective is to return a correctly associated column (in this case: c(2,3)) i can add back in `Dselect`. Thanks.

Comment: class(D) says it's a dataframe (it returns "data.frame").    

dput(D) shows something like (consider the actual D has a column per month):    

`structure(list('01' = c(0.0787998558083221,..., 0.062248188622537), '02' = c(0.077476783314289,...
...), .Names = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
"09", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))`

Comment: The data structure reminds me of SQL, maybe you could look into the `sqldf` package to see if there is a convenient solution. Right now, this selection process seems overly complicated.